# How to call function unknown at design time from a dll in c++

Tags: c++, dll

In my program, user will provide a dll at run time.
User will also provide the function name and its parameters at run time.
Definition of this function is written in the given dll.
So the function name and dll name is unknown at design time.
Is there any way to call this function at runtime in the code.

Answer (score 1):

if use windows, you can ref about LoadLibrary: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

or Linux:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html

Comment: LoadLibrary/[GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx) are what you'll need on Windows. LoadLibrary by itself won't be enough.